# Cannot log into my site on iOS devices when "Disable Cross-Site Tracking" is on

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, auth0, cross-site

We have an Angular 9 SPA on the front-end with a .Net Core 5 WebAPI on the backend.
We’re using Auth0 as our authentication server.
For some reason, on iPhones, after the user logs in (on Auth0’s login screen) and gets redirected back to our web app, the web app just hangs. We’ve tried this on two different iPhones, using Safari, Chrome and Edge browsers, and they all exhibit the same problem.
It is working fine on Android and Windows devices.

Now, when I turn off “Prevent Cross-Site Tracking” on the web browser on the iPhones, then everything works again. So, I turned this feature off on Chrome and Edge (on the two iPhones) and everything started working again on both these browsers.

I’m not sure if this could be an Auth0 issue, or maybe something on the Angular app or the Web API. I’ve been Googling it for a bit and cannot find anything. Unfortunately, web browsers on iPhones don’t seem to have the “F12 Developer Tools”, so I can’t even see what error is occurring!

Has anyone come across the same issue? Is there perhaps anything like "F12 Developer Tools" that the desktop browsers have that I could activate on the iPhone browsers?

Thanks